# Multiple dynamic radio buttons based on checkbox selection

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, forms, radio-button

I have a form selection that allows users to select a product from a dynamically generated MySQL list and then rate the product using radio buttons.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="$row[ProdID]" name="Product[]" id="Product$row[ProdID]" onclick="showhide_div($row[ProdID])" />$row[ProductName]

<div id="div$row[CatID]" style="display:none">
<input type="radio" name="ProductQual$row[ProdID]" id="PQ$row[ProdID]" value="1" /> Poor&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="ProductQual$row[ProdID]" id="PQ$row[ProdID]" value="2" /> Fair&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="ProductQual$row[ProdID]" id="PQ$row[ProdID]" value="3" /> Good&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="ProductQual$row[ProdID]" id="PQ$row[ProdID]" value="4" /> Excellent&nbsp;&nbsp;
</div>
```

I want to put the selected radio value for each of the "checked" products into a MySQL table

```
-----------------
| ProdID(a) | 3 |
| ProdID(b) | 1 |
-----------------
```

I know I need to for_each each selected Product but I am having trouble figuring out how to related the correct radio button from the overall $POST to the Product during the for_each loop to put the values into the MySQL table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a more elegant way of doing things, but this would be my solution.  I wrapped your checkboxes and radios in `<label></label>` tags, so the text is clickable (a good accessibility guideline to practice, too).  RADIOs are generated with a unique ID for each product.

```
<?php

echo '<label><input type="checkbox" name="product_' . $row['ProdID'] . '" id="product_' . $row['ProdID'] . '" onclick="javascript:showhide_div(' . $row['ProdID'] . ')" /> ' . $row['ProductName'] . '</label>';

echo <<<EOT
<div id="div{$row['ProdID']}" style="display:none;">
<label><input type="radio" name="productquality_{$row['ProdID']}" value="1" /> Poor</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="productquality_{$row['ProdID']}" value="2" /> Fair</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="productquality_{$row['ProdID']}" value="3" /> Good</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="productquality_{$row['ProdID']}" value="4" /> Excellent</label>
</div>
EOT;
```

And on the back-end, all ratings fields are parsed and inserted into a table.

```
<?php

foreach ( $_REQUEST as $k=>$v){   // Step through each _REQUEST (_POST or _GET) variable

    if ( strpos( $k, 'productquality' ) !== false ){    // Only parse productquality_X variables
        $parts = explode( '_', $k );    // Split at the underscore
        $id = $parts[1];    // ID is the part after the underscore

        // Do something, like insert into MySQL.  In reality best to escape the values, to make sure to prevent injection.
        mysql_query( ' INSERT INTO `quality` ( ProdID, Rating ) VALUES ( ' . $id . ', ' . $v . '); ');
    }
}
```